# Endomorphisms of a Lie algebra representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $V$ be a representation of a reductive Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ over $\mathbb C$ and let $\mathfrak b$ be a Borel subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$. Let $V^+$ be the $\mathfrak b$-eigen subspace of $V$. Let $End_{\mathfrak g}(V)$ be the $\mathfrak g$-module endomorphisms of $V$. I have seen somewhere that $End_{\mathfrak g}(V)=End_{\mathbb C}(V^+)$. I am not sure if this is true. If this is true then a proof of this statement will be quite helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by the $\mathfrak{b}$ eigenspace? At a guess the common eigenvectors of a Borel would be the highest weights (in each irreducible component)

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is one (up to a scalar multiple) for each irreducible components.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time to cook up a proof of this but I suspect (if it is true) it should follow from the fact that you can generate a whole irrep from the highest weight space. Indeed if we allow ourselves to pick a complementary Borel we get a CSA and thus root and weight systems and then the action of the endomorphism on a given weight space is constrained by the action on the weight spaces "above" it and so ultimately the highest weight space. This looks pretty clear in an irrep but it is less clear to me that there are no problems with this line of reasoning in a general rep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things are not quite as easy. If you have non-zero eigenvectors for different weights, then the sum of these spaces is not an eigenspace. Moreover, any homomorphism of $\mathfrak g$-modules preserves the weights. So what you should do is take the weights $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ for which the $\mathfrak b$-eigenspace $V^+_i$ is non-trivial. (Equivalently, this means that the isotypical component of weight $\lambda_i$ in $V$ is non-trivial.) Then $Hom_{\mathfrak g}(V,V)\cong\oplus_{i=1}^nHom_{\mathbb C}(V^+_i,V^+_i)$. The simpliest way to prove this is via isotopical components. So you define $V^{(\lambda_i)}\subset V$ to be the $\mathfrak g$-submodule generated by $V^+_i$ and prove that $V=\oplus_{i=1}^NV^{(\lambda_i)}$. Using that any $\mathfrak g$-homomorphism has to map a $\mathfrak b$-eigenvector to a $\mathfrak b$-eigenvector you conclude that this decomposition is preserved by an $\mathfrak g$-homomorphism. This reduces the argument to the case that $V=V^{(\lambda)}$ for one weight $\lambda$ and for this the proof is a simple variation of the proof of uniquness in the theorem of the highest weight.